# How to check Airplane mode in background in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, airplane-mode

I have application which is working best with Wifi,3G..
Now what i want is i want to check in background if Airplane mode is going to be on at any moment and i want to popup alert saying "Airplane mode is On."
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think different approach, check your mobile Network availability rather than the Airplane mode and Show a Generic Alert `There is no network Available` for example.

Check This link [iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is practically impossible unless the user does it within a 10 minute time frame of your application entering background mode.

Comment: Your best bet is to go with what AhmadTK has suggested.