# How to restart airplane mode programmatically iphone

Tags: iphone, airplane-mode

I am studying about coding and I got a question to control airplane mode in iphone programmatically

For android phone, we can use usb connection and adb  to send unix command to control airplane mode.

Is there any possibility to control airplane mode by unix command and lighting cable connection?

I was checking 
[ios: turn on/off airplane mode from code for iPhone / iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075797/ios-turn-on-off-airplane-mode-from-code-for-iphone-ipad)

[How to check Airplane mode in background in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814947/how-to-check-airplane-mode-in-background-in-iphone)

but i am not clearly sure if it is possible...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggling AirPlane mode in iOS Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469425/toggling-airplane-mode-in-ios-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

No, you just can't do that.

An app has to adopt to the current network state, not control it.

Comment: thanks!! so not like Android phone, we can't use debug or developer mode to wirely restart airplane mode ? um... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to access the private API and this would mean, you can't upload the app to the `App Store` because it is not allowed to use the private API in productive mode.